# Тормозит игра на android

Tags: android

Пишу первую игру на андроид. И возникла такая проблема: поставил на задний фон активити изображение png в Full HD. На экране есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должен открываться фрагмент. Но при нажатии на нее фрагмент открывается не мгновенно, а примерно 800 мс. Если с заднего фона уберу картинку и просто закрашу цветом, то отклик мгновенный. Как сделать так, чтобы отклик был быстрее?

Comment: Попробуйте сжать изображение. Также как вариант загрузить изображение на активити раньше, чем пользователь нажмет кнопку, если это возможно. Лучше будет если вы приведете пример добавления вашего изображения, код кнопки отображения вашего изображения.

Comment: Картинка всегда загружается перед нажатием. При нажатии открывается пустой фрагмент. Код добавить нет возможности пока. Скажите, если использовать векторную графику(векторное изображение), отклик уменьшится?